# Binding a regular expression as an observable in knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm new to KnockoutJS. I know how to define an observable that will be used to change the text of an element (or be updated from a text element), however, I want the data in my model to be actually a regular expression with read/write access. I want to set it using a `textarea` like:

```
<textarea data-bind="value: regex"></textarea>
```

And show it on the page using:

```
<span data-bind="text: regex"></span>
```

Now the initialization is working:

```
//inside the model
this.regex = ko.observable( /,/g );
```

And both the `textarea` and `span` get updated (because the native regular expression variable has a `toString()` function that works perfectly well showing a string representation of the regular expression). But when I change the `regex` in the `textarea` the `span` doesn't update. It seems like setting the observable is failing.

This is understandable because the `value` from `textarea` is just a text and in order to convert it to an actual regular expression, some code is needed. I have the code. Let's call it `function str2regex()` with a body similar to this:

```
//this is pseudo code and doesn't neccesarily work
function str2regex( str )
  var r = str.match( "^\/(.+?)\/([mig])*$" );
  if ( r ) {
    if ( r[2] === null ) {
      return new RegExp( r[1] );
    } else {
      return new RegExp( r[1], r[2] );
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

How can I set the value of type regular expression in my model using the text that is coming from the `textarea`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should transform your `str2regex` to computed observable like this:

```
// str2regex transformed to computed observable
self.regex = ko.computed(function(){
    var m = self.regex_string().match(/^\/(.+)\/([mig])*$/);
    return m ? new RegExp(m[1], m[2]) : null;
});
```

But you still should track your regex string editable in textarea (`regex_string` observable in my code).

Take a look: http://jsbin.com/ofehuj/2/edit

Comment: yeah, that's what I did eventually. It would be nice if I could use a textarea to set the regular expression directly without defining a new variable in the model. But anyway, I guess this works.